# How to hide Dokan vendor info in product page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, dokan

there is a plugin called "[Dokan Vendor Info Hider – Hide Vendor info from Store-list and store page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dokan-vendor-info-hider/)
" that has not been updated for a long time and does not work.
Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide Dokan vendor info, you need to use this code in your theme’s functions.php file –

```
function dokan_remove_seller_info_option( $tabs ){  
  unset ($tabs ['seller']); 
  return $tabs;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'dokan_remove_seller_info_option', 11 );
```